# Шаблонизатор TWIG. Как внедрить в тэг if шаблонизатора TWIG HTML-тэги

Tags: php, twig

В тег `span` передается json при помощи jquery. Как внедрить тег `span` в TWIG-тег?

```
 {% if product.product_id == <span></span> %}
   <h3>{{ product.name }}</h3>
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: ничего не ясно.

Comment: Твиг исполнится до загрузки в браузере. Поэтому он понятия не имеет о твоем джквери и прочей клиентской пляске.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это вам подойдет https://symfony.ru/doc/current/frontend/encore/server-data.html

`<h3 data-poduct-name="">{{ product.name }}</h3>`

И использовать дата-атрибут как контейнер для данных из jQuery.